# How can I pass keywords as arguments that can be passed to update-in?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

On the following function:

```
(defn update-map [state key1 key2] 
    (update-in state [key1 key2] update-fn)
)
```

If I call the function with:

```
(update-map state :somekey :otherkey)
```

I receive a null pointer.

However, if I run the same code of inside the function on the REPL, or substitute the arguments passed to the update-in function to hard keywords, it works flawlessly.

How can I pass keywords as arguments that can be passed to update-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have a `(def state ...)` somewhere and are confusing the local `state` in your function with the global `state` var.  This code shows what is happening:

```
(defn update-fn [some-map key1 key2]
  (update-in some-map [key1 key2] inc ))

(def data {:k1 {:k2 42}})

(update-fn data :k1 :k2) => {:k1 {:k2 43}}
```

So it works as desired.  If it is still not working for you, you'll need to update your question and show how `state` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Either state or update-fn is not defined.

You can improve your function to take any amount of keywords using `&`

```
(defn update-map [state & ks]
  (update-in state ks update-fn))
```